# Scanning a keyboard matrix

Tags: circuit-design, multiplexer, keyboard, matrix

I recently watched a [video](https://youtu.be/h-NM1xSSzHQ) on YouTube by Branch Education.

In this video, they describe two methods for scanning the matrix:

1. Sequentially apply a voltage across each column so that at any instant only one column is active. However, this drains the battery and an efficient way is developed, which scans only when required (described below).
2. All columns are active and when a key is pressed, the  columns are sequentially turned off to determine which key in the row was pressed. This is done by recording a drop in voltage when the column having a pressed key is turned off. Please watch 5:07 to 5:50 if I'm not clear.

The problem is the second method. I checked a few websites, but this method is not mentioned. Also, how can you record two keys of the same row being pressed simultaneously? At 5:45, two voltage drops are recorded for L & A key. How is this possible? Shouldn't it be constant high? Because when a column is inactive, all other columns are active. So if a column having a pressed key is turned off, the other column also having a pressed key is still active.

Is this method really used? What is the best way to scan a matrix which also solves the ghosting problem?

Comment: Sounds like utter nonsense.

Comment: What sounds like utter nonsense. The method or question? @Finbarr

Comment: The concept of saving power by having all columns active all the time instead of just one at a time. And the mention of needing "additional microprocessors".

Comment: Concept of saving power... Not my words. Sorry if additional microprocessors has confused you. But i mean a simple circuit design.

Comment: I think all possible methods to scan a matrix can be used. It just depends on the situation and what the hardware is capable to do and what the software does to achieve it. There is no best method. If you want to solve a ghosting problem, you add diodes as it is impossible for the software to know after a couple of buttons which are really pushed or just appears to be pushed as the three other buttons short the same pins as the fourth button.

Comment: it makes sense to briefly enable all columns to detect if a key has been pressed .. do a normal scan only if a press is detected ... that would save power because less code is run

Comment: You can enable all columns in the sleep state and use a pin change interrupt to wake up the MCU. Then you can run whatever you like to detect the switch.